# Unable to amend ContentTypeProperty in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

My sharepoint site has a number of mandatory Document Type Properties. I can set all bar one of them using
`ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(1).Value = "Something required"`

However, one of these required properties allows multiple selections from a 'library structure' (or at least that is how it is described)

I've noticed that this property is listed not as the value, but rather as the Value(0)

None of the following seem to work:

`ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(9).Value = "Library requirement"` 
`ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(9).Value.Value(0) = "Library requirement"` 
`ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(9).Value(0) = "Library requirement"`

I can amend the value, when there's one already present (using the last of the three listed above). But if the property is blank, the script falls over with a Type Mismatch error.

I'm anticipating a number of documents being generated automatically, so anything that will help my colleagues get them sorted properly would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify the "I can amend the value, when there's one already present"? What is the "one"? a property? a property's value?... Could you provide an example of that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't being very clear.
If I *manually* add a value to the particular contenttype property (via the Document Information Panel), then it can be *subsequently* updated by the script. But if it's *empty*, it cannot be populated by the script.
Hopefully that helps - and thanks for taking an interest in my problem!

Comment: I know the "ContentTypePropertie" is read-only so you cannot create/delete/rename it in VBA. The value it holds should be changeable. So, the "ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(9).Value(0)" is not the property but the value of the "property(9)", correct? Does it mean this "property(9)" has (could have) several values, like "property(9)(0), property(9)(1)", etc.? Do you mean you need to have at least "property(9)(0)" assigned outside of VBA in order to modify it, or to add, say, "property(9)(2)" and assign a value to it? etc.

Comment: ...There are too many possibilities not clarified by you. I know, this is an awfully confusing situation, given Microsoft's unwillingness (inability?) to provide minimal meaningful documentation/help lately.  I know some "list-type" properties cannot be addressed by direct calling (those treated internally as a collection of objects). To work with those you need to set a loop of this type "For Each...'object' In Collection  / Next 'object'" and deal with those 'objects' inside the loop...

Comment: ... also, if you look "For i=1 to n"-type and the app does resorting internally as you make changes to the elements then, sometimes, you need to figure out how to deal with that. I hope these comments might give you some useful ideas. I wished I could actually work/test your problem myself, otherwise it's all a supposition. Good luck.